# What errors that can't be detected by testing techniques but rather by guessing?

Tags: automated-testing

Error guessing is known to be one way of knowing the error from previous experiences. however, it's a technique that usually testers perform if all other formal techniques (like Whitebox testing or other blackbox testing) failed to identify the error.

Scenario: Assuming that I have automatic bus door that opens once the bus arrives at the station for people with disabilities.

My question is as follows: What kind of errors can take place (in the scenario above) and can be detected only by guessing not any other formal techniques?

Comment: A major problem with this particular questions it that it doesn't have *an answer*. Which "kind of error" would receive the green check? The coolest? The most upvoted? I'm not saying you don't have an interesting question, I'm just afraid this isn't the proper venue to ask it. Sorry!

Comment: thanks for your comment but I just wanna clarify that I posted this question not to get a "cool" answer.. but rather to get some ideas that might help me in solving a real complicated testing related case study.. Anyways, I understand that it's considered an open question but I needed some guidance because I couldn't find good references on this issue online.

Comment: I 100% believe you. I see you don't currently have the reputation you need to chat, but when you do (which shouldn't take long, a question/answer or two) bring your problem to chat. It's exactly for this kind of thing - with a little luck, an expert or two will be able to help solve the problem or, at the very least, find a truly answerable question you can ask! :-)

Comment: Yes I am actually new here.. that's why I don't know most of the rules maybe. Thanks :)